# Css "transform: scale()" makes element grow outside of container

Tags: html, css

I have the HTML and CSS Below:

**HTML**

```
<div class="div">
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <td>column 1</td>
            <td>column 2</td>
            <td>column 3</td>
            <td>column 4</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.div
{
    background-color: red;
    padding: 5px;
}
.table
{
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
    width: 100%;

    -moz-transform: scale(1.5); /* Firefox */
    -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -o-transform: scale(1.5); /* Opera */
    -o-transform-origin: 0 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.5); /* Safari And Chrome */
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
    transform: scale(1.5); /* Standard Property */
    transform-origin: 0 0;  /* Standard Property */
}
```

Also, please see [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hmeLR/) to see the output.

The question is, why does the `table` grow outside of the `div` container?  This does not make sense to me.  The `width` style attribute is set to `100%`.  I expect the the table to stay in the `div` container since I have no `width` limit on it.

Is there a way to make the table remain in the boundaries of the container after the `transform: scale()`?

Thank you

Comment: seems because of padding to `div` element.

Comment: @Mr_Green I don't think so.  If you remove the padding, you won't be able to see the container.

Comment: if I apply scaling also to the div element then also the problem is there but when I add a letter in div then the div is looking good but the table is going down because of the letter. [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hmeLR/1/)

Comment: So, you should do scaling to the div instead of table.. realized lately :D [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hmeLR/2/).

Comment: That's not my question though :)  I need to to scale the table.

Comment: yes I know.. if you observe you can see that the table is 150% bigger than the parent container i.e `div` (_remove padding in calculation_) [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hmeLR/3/). that is what scaling do.. or did I still didn't get your explanation?

Comment: I think you do get my explanation.  I need to know how I could scale the table and keep it in the boundaries of the container.  My sample is a small sample of a much bigger scale situation.

Comment: Then you need to scale the table less than `1.0` (100%). if you increase the scaling (> 100%) then the table will go out of div. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your best bet here, if you need to use transform: scale(), is to apply the transform to the div. The table will inherit it, and be contained within it. Transforms create a new context for the element, which is why the div isn't growing with it.

The bigger question is, what are you hoping to see as the end result? If it's just resizing the table, the using a transform seems like a bit of overkill that introduces some complications. Wouldn't it be simpler to just do something like:

```
.table {
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
    width: 100%;
}

.table td {
    width: 25%;
    height: 2.5em;
    font-size: 1.5em;
}
```

If all you're trying to do is re-size the elements, that should give you a similar result.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try this css:

```
 .div
{
background-color: red;
padding: 0px;
}
```

Comment: If you turn off the padding, you are just hiding the container.  If you inspect the element in chrome or firefox, you will see that the div does not grow.